# How to pass ArrayList size from onBindViewHolder to getItemCount() method in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I have this array inside onBindViewHolder method like that.

```
checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(id);
                String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
                String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
                ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
                newStatusList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                int size =  newStatusList.size();
```

I want to pass size to below method

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return size;
```

By doing that getItemCount  won't get any values in it, this means I don't see any item. If I want to put that code in the Adapter constructor the items get showed, but after deleting a row, the row gets recreated again. Because I can't put

```
newStatusList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

inside adapter constructor, since I can't access ViewHolder position inside adapter constructor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You know that `getItemCount()` is for backing data count of the adapter right? Is that array what feeding data for your adapter? If it is so, why don't you declare it as a global field in your adapter?

Comment: @Kozmotronik I did that thank you.

Comment: @Kozmotronik would you mind take another look of the code, because it won't fix it yet. I added relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `int size=0;` globally inside Adapter.
also, create this array list when the constructor gets called.
so you can have the list prepared before `getItemCount()` gets called.

```
Adaper(){
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        integers.add(2);
        integers.add(8);
        integers.add(2);
        integers.add(61);
        integers.add(3);
        integers.add(75);
        size = integers.size();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it..

Comment: I did that, but I have an array like that in onBindViewHolder  ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));

Comment: onBindViewHolder is used to display the all the positions from array. Thats why it has position parameter. 
This list will be repeated for every position.
You should have adapter items size before calling onBindViewHolder, so you can tell adapter to repeat onBindViewHolder according to items size.

Comment: could you post full adapter so i can give you some help.

Comment: Look, I added relevant code. Sorry for accepting then unaccepting the answer because problem still not fixed. I'll accepted answer if I fixed.

Comment: checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(id);
                String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
                String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
                ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
Send this list inside Adapter(newStatusList) like this when you set adapter on recyclerView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246207/discussion-between-beant-singh-and-omer123).

Answer (score 1):

```
 checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(id);
            String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
            String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
            ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
            newStatusList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
         
            int size =  newStatusList.size();
```

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

```
    return newStatusList.size();
```